# Get Int from NSData

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdata

I am using a library which has the ability to pull data from a BTLE device and place it in NSData. However i need to pull out the individual lines of data into int's. How do i do this?

here is the code:

```
- (void)realDataCallBackWithData:(NSData *)realData{
      if (realData == nil) {
              DLog(@"error");
              return;
      }
      VTRealObject *rObj = [VTO2Parser parseO2RealObjectWithData:realData];
      self.descLab.text = [rObj description];
}

- (UILabel *)descLab{
      if (!_descLab) {
              _descLab =  elalloc initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
              _descLab.numberOfLines = 0;
              _descLab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
              [self.view addSubview:_descLab];
      }
      return _descLab;
}
```

here is the library VTO2Parser.h code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "VTO2Info.h"
#import "VTO2Object.h"
#import "VTO2WaveObject.h"
#import "VTRealObject.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface VTO2Parser : NSObject

// @brief parse O2 information
// @param infoData infoData from peripheral
+ (VTO2Info *)parseO2InfoWithData:(NSData * _Nonnull)infoData;

// @brief parse O2 object
// @param fileData fileData from peripheral
+ (VTO2Object *)parseO2ObjectWithData:(NSData * _Nonnull)fileData;

// @brief parse O2 Wave array .
// @param waveData waveData from   VTO2Object
+ (NSArray <VTO2WaveObject *>*)parseO2WaveObjectArrayWithWaveData:(NSData * 
_Nonnull)waveData;

// @brief parse O2 Real-time data
// @param realData realData from peripheral
+ (VTRealObject *)parseO2RealObjectWithData:(NSData *)realData;

// @brief parse O2 Real PPG data
// @param realPPG real PPG data from peripheral
+ (NSArray <VTRealPPG *>*)parseO2RealPPGWithData:(NSData *)realPPG;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And also here is the VTO2Object.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface VTRealObject : NSObject

// @brief blood oxygen value
@property (nonatomic, assign) u_char spo2;

// @brief heart rate
@property (nonatomic, assign) u_short hr;

// @brief battery value
@property (nonatomic, assign) u_char battery;

// @brief battery status
@property (nonatomic, assign) u_char batState;

// @brief Perfusion Index value
@property (nonatomic, assign) u_char pi;

// @brief lead status . for BabyO2:       0: Probe off     1: Lead normal       2: Lead off
@property (nonatomic, assign) u_char leadState;

// @brief motion value
@property (nonatomic, assign) u_char vector; 

@end


@interface VTRealPPG : NSObject

// @brief Infrared
@property (nonatomic, assign) int ir;

// @brief RLED
@property (nonatomic, assign) int red;

// @brief motion
@property (nonatomic, assign) u_char motion;

@end


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

The end result within the app looks like this:

> <VTRealObject: 0x28368ae60> -- {
> batState = 0;
> battery = 66; hr = 76; leadState = 1; pi =20; spo2 = 98; vector = 0;}

How can i get seperate Int's from the above data so i can assign it to individual labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your VTRealObject `rObj` already contains all the values you want and will hand them to you as properties or method return values.

If not, then you need to do exactly what your VTO2Parser is already doing: look directly at the `realData` and parse it, finding the values that it contains and interpreting them. For that, you have to know the *format* of the `realData`. The task is then easy. For example, if you know that the first two / four bytes of the `realData` are a `long` representing the `batState`, it's trivial to read them as a `long`. And so on.

Comment: thank you for the information, how exactly would i do this though, would you please provide an example?

Comment: No, impossible — because you've concealed all the facts. I have no idea what a VTRealObject is. You do. I have no idea what's in your NSData. You do. You didn't give _any_ of the relevant information in your question, so no more specific answer is possible. But I assure you that people _do_ parse NSData into a sequence of numbers (`long` or whatever) all the time; how to do that, once you know the format in which your NSData encodes its information, has been explained here many, many times already.

Comment: i didn't realise i had not provided enough information, that is easily rectified. I will update the question with the library information for the VTO2Parser.h

Comment: thank you for pointing out that i had not included enough information, i have now updated the question with the information, is this now enough information for you to provide an example?

Comment: Cool so what’s the problem? What I said is right. For example `@property (nonatomic, assign) u_char battery;` means there is a `battery` property just waiting for to fetch it and do whatever you like.

Comment: so basically i should ignore the VTO2Parser and pull the information directly from VTO2Object instead? I apologise if this seems silly, i have not coded for 4 years and am very rusty, its surprising how much you can forget in that time.

Comment: Well you need the parser to do the parsing into the real object. But once you do, instead of calling `description`, talk to the real object to get its property values.

Comment: sorry but would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: `u_char battery = rObj.battery;`

Comment: And then you can use `stringWithFormat` to turn that into text that you can display in your interface.

Comment: Thanks @matt, I'll give it a go tomorrow